# Webkit columns find range of visible text

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, webkit

I have a piece of HTML which I am displaying inside a `UIWebView` using Webkit stylesheet attributes. I use Webkit to display the HTML in columns in order to simulate a book.

Only one column is visible at a time (one column represents one page). Now, I am trying to find the range of the visible HTML so that I can insert a span element right before the first visible word.

I managed to get the HTML element which contains the first visible word by using the JavaScript function, `document.elementAtPoint`(I might have the function name wrong), and changed its CSS class. but that just isn't accurate enough for me. I need it to be accurate up to the first visible word.

The idea is the create a column break at the first visible word when the fontsize is increased or decreased. I can using JavaScript to figure out in which column the element is, and programmatically scroll the user to that column, but first I need to get the element in there.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using CSS columns (e.g. `-webkit-column-count`)? Perhaps you could post a demo? In particular, it sounds like @DavidMulder might be able to help a _lot_ more if he had a clearer idea of what you're already doing and want to achieve. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSSOM View Module specification adds [`caretPositionFromPoint(x, y)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-document-caretpositionfrompoint) to the `Document` interface, which returns a caret position for the specified *x* and *y* co-ordinates. WebKit supports [`caretRangeFromPoint`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-cssom-view-20090804/#dom-documentview-caretrangefrompoint), a close analogue from an earlier specification, which returns a [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html).

It is possible that the word has been hyphenated and thus spans two columns, so rather than wrapping the first word in a span you may wish to consider the more naive approach of inserting the `span` directly at the cursor point. Here's an example:

```js
var caretPos = document.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y);

if (caretPos)
    caretPos.insertNode(document.createElement('span'));
```

**Demo *(WebKit only—click to insert spans)*:** http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/Aw9aV/

One final consideration: it is possible that WebKit will eventually stop supporting `caretRangeFromPoint` in lieu of `caretPositionFromPoint`; if so, you will need to adapt your code. Also note that the latter returns a `CaretPosition` which may not implement the `insertNode` method. The spec is still at WD, so be mindful that it is still in flux.

Comment: Ok, I have tried everything I could think of, but couldn't get it to work in a UIWebView. Any pointers?

Comment: Ah, shoot! I can't immediately think of anything; I know the `caretRangeFromPoint` method is supported on WebKit on iPad, so all I can guess is that there's something peculiar about running JS through a `UIWebView`? Maybe you could post an example of the code you're using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have tagged you in the above reply @EZFrag.

Comment: Ok, I awarded the bounty to you, since it is the closest to what I need. I will have to continue this discussion later though as I have been assign to another high priority item. Thanks for your help thus far. I hope we can continue investigating this issue at a later stage.

Comment: @EZFrag you and me both. I was on holiday for the past week so I couldn't get back, but I feel kinda chagrinned that this didn't work out for you. I'm working on something that uses this method, so I know it works; just need to figure out what's odd about this particular case!

Comment: I have tried other approaches as well...(Rangy, and a couple other odd scripts) all of which failed when used with the UIWebView. Works fine with every other browsers out there... I'm afraid that I might have to use the Webkit framework for IOS.... I really don't want to do this... it will be weeks of work own the drain...

Comment: @EZFrag I'm sure I read somewhere about an equivalent internal method, which might give you a start? I'm puzzled why the JS method wouldn't be working, can only guess it's something specific to `UIWebView`. (Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971840/uiwebview-javascript-injection)

Comment: Okie dokie, I have it more or less. My Method is not 100%, I believe it can be improved significantly. I loop through every coordinate from the top of the screen, until I hit a letter (99% of the time the first word on the page). I then generate a xpath reference for that location (Element XPath and text index). Then I hide everything in front of that location. As in everything. It is extremely resource intensive, as I'm making hundreds of Javascript call to the webview trying to find the first word, but that will do for now.

Comment: Oh God. You're right, that sounds like it could be improved. I actually feel awful that I can't suggest a better solution… yet. I can tell this will be one of those SO questions that plague me for months, I'll be back if I can think of a nicer answer for this. Could you perhaps post a JSFiddle with the actual HTML/CSS and some dummy copy?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nog entirely sure what you are currently doing, but at the very least I should be able to give some useful tips, as I have some experience building page browsing systems in javascript.

- First of all, in CSS3 you can define columns https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns , which will automatically split up the content into different columns within a single element (where a single column has the full width of the uiwebview) and next add browsing controls which move the entire element containing the element (using css3 3d translations for smooth hardware accelerated motion and you know the width of the columns so you don't need to worry about what the first word on the page is). In which case you don't need to worry about splitting up the column breaks yourself. (Though, as I said, I am not sure to what extend you are already doing this).
- Alternatively you may decide to wrap all your content in small inline-blocks (as older column implementations did) or even up to the point of single inline elements, each containing a single word. (Though this doesn't seem necessary anymore)
- Lastly, work is being done on http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-regions/ which will make this even easier in the future, but for now it's only available in chrome and ie10

On the other hand, you might already be doing this or I might be missing the point, in which case I would need to see some code before I can give you a more specific answer. (I can think of various javascript tricks to work with letters within a text, but none seem necessary in your case)